# Java Corrupt JPEG data ... sending image Client-Server-Client

Tags: java, image, sockets, server, client

My error when sending an image Client-Server-Client is "Corrupt JPEG data: 4350674 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9" What I can change? Here is my code :

**SERVER**

```
 InputStream is = klienciRemoteScreen[1].getInputStream();
 OutputStream os = klienciRemoteScreen[0].getOutputStream();                            

                  byte[] bytesize = new byte[4];                              
                  is.read(bytesize);                                                                              
                  int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytesize).asIntBuffer().get();
                  byte [] image= new byte [size];
                  byte[]bufferimage = new byte [1];
                  os.write(bytesize);
                  os.flush();
                  int count;
                  while((count = is.read(image)) > 0)
                  {
                     os.write(image);
                     os.flush();                                                          
                   }
                     os.close();
```

**CLIENT sending image to server**

```
OutputStream os = noguiklient.sockRemoteScreen.getOutputStream();

Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(dim);  
    Robot robot = new Robot();                                            
BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();           

ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", byteArrayOutputStream);

byte[] size = 
ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(byteArrayOutputStream.size()).array();            
int sizeas = ByteBuffer.wrap(size).asIntBuffer().get();

        os.write(size);
        os.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        os.close();
```

**CLIENT Receiving from server**

```
JFrame okno = new JFrame();
    okno.setSize(1300, 1000);
    okno.setTitle(" Remote screen");
    okno.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(1300,1000);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    okno.add(panel);        
    okno.setVisible(true);


    InputStream is = Klient.sockRemoteScreen.getInputStream();
    File photo = new File ("photo") ;
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photo);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
    is.read(buffer);        
    int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).asIntBuffer().get();
    byte[] image = new byte [size];

    int count;
    int i =0 ;
    while((count = is.read(image)) > 0)
    {
        fos.write(image);
        fos.flush();

    }

       ImageIcon screen = new ImageIcon("photo");
       Image imagefinal = screen.getImage();                
       imagefinal = 
       imagefinal.getScaledInstance(okno.getWidth(),okno.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

       BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
          Graphics graphics = panel.getGraphics();
while(true)
{
          graphics.drawImage(imagefinal, 0, 0, panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), panel);     
}
```

[Example of this bad Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILB1f.png)

When I try to send with ImageIO everything is fine but I want to try with bytes and there is a problem.
Thank you :)

Comment: why do you call `flush()` in each iteration of the loop?

Comment: To be sure that everything has been sent :) but you are right , its wasting

Comment: it might even be the cause of your problems. please try it with the `flush()` call *after* the `for` loop

Comment: I removed flush() from the loop and now I have only after ,,                  os.write(bytesize); " and after loop but still the same image